# pgfplots produces unexpected graph of simple function

Tags: pgfplots

I want to plot a simple exponential function 2^x. The code I'm using is below. The plot hits the x axis where I set the lower value for the domain, -6 in the example. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots} \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{$f(x) = 2^x$} \label{fig:Exp2x}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    mark=none,
    domain= -6:2,
    samples=20,
    smooth,
    axis x line=center,
    axis y line=center,
    xlabel=$x$, xlabel style={anchor=west}]
 \addplot[thick] {2^x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It doesn't hit x axis but there have very small value: 0.015625. What you expected that graph would look like?

Comment: @Zarko: you are correct that there is a small value; indeed, there will ''always' be a small valur What is disconcerting is that if I set the domain to -2:2, the plot will look the same, with the curve SEEMING to hit the axis at -2. If pgfplots can show a clear gap between the axis and the curve at -2 when the domain is -6:2, why does it  go away when the domain is -2:2?? Try a couple of domains and the effect will be clear.

Comment: You must define `ymin`. If you observe distance between `ytick` you will see, that the first `ytick`  is closer to abscisa ... it is not at `y=0` (as you expected) bat at value  defined with star bounding of domain. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add also ymin=-.5, so your ymin is not the value calculated for your's function.
Complete code:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots} \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{$f(x) = 2^x$} \label{fig:Exp2x}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                mark=none,
                domain= -2:2,
                samples=50,
                smooth,
                ymin=-.5,% <--
                axis x line=center,
                axis y line=center,
                xlabel=$x$, xlabel style={anchor=west}]
                \addplot[thick] {2^x};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Correct output:

[image]

**ADD** Also with the domain -4:2 You will see the expected answer:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The comment above applies here. I'm very grateful for the willingness of you and others on this forum to share your knowledge.

Answer (score 5):

You need to define where does the abscissa lie in your diagram. Its default position at selected `axis lines` is not at place as you expected.

Without explicit defined position of abscissa it is drawn through the point defined by starting point of drawing function's domain. Saying that, at `domain=-5:2` it lie at `y(-5)`, at `domain=-2:2` it lie at `y(-2)`, but at defining `ymin=0` lie at `y=0` and at `ymin=-1` it will lie at `y=0`.

According to this facts, you will observe that at selected axis lines distance between abscisa and `ytick=1` at the first two cases are different as they are distances between others `ytick`s.

So if you rewrite your MWE to:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\caption{$f(x) = 2^x$} \label{fig:Exp2x}
\pgfplotsset{           % common axis settings
    width = 78mm,       % that images are parallel 
    axis lines=center,
    xlabel=$x$, xlabel style={anchor=west},
    ymin=0,             % <--- that abscisa go through y(0)
    samples=101,
    no marks,
}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain=-5:2,
            ]
\addplot +[thick] {2^x};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\quad    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain=-2:2,
            ]
\addplot +[thick] {2^x};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

result is what you expected:

[image]

This features of `pgfplots` you may declare as bug, but at many situations this is desired (for example at logarithmic axis where `y(0)` not exist, i.e. is at minus infinity).

For better understanding aforementioned, test your diagram  when for axis you select  default style and add `grid` option to axis:

```
\pgfplotsset{           % common axis setings
    width = 78mm,       % that immages are parralel 
    grid,               % to see grid 
    xlabel=$x$, xlabel style={anchor=west},
    samples=101,
    no marks,
}
```

In such cases results are

[image]

Comment: Thank you. There's so much I don't know and/or understand about pgfplots. You don't expect that lack of skill to jump up and bite you when trying to plot a very simple function. I couldn't manage without this forum.

Comment: @TonyK, what you like to tell me with your comment?  Sorry, but no one force you to be a member of this site.

Comment: I fear you misunderstood my comment. It was meant to be a very big thank you to you and others like you who share your knowledge on this forum. Perhaps I phrased it poorly, and I apologize if something I wrote offended you. That was certainly not my intent, my intent was quite the opposite.

Comment: English is not my native language, so it can happen that something has been lost in translation ... Anyway, In my answer I put quite effort in explanation why your problem happens and show, how can it be avoided.